# How do i paste outside content into vim?

Tags: vim, editor, copy-paste, neovim

I got a problem while using vim.i can't figured out any solution  to paste content from outside into vim.so can any one please make my job easy.

I tried lot from from stack overflow and more. but none of them worked worked.set paste option worked but without indentation.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking about. Can't you paste or do you have trouble with indentation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

### Temporary

Your question depends on which OS you're using.
Let's assume that you're on a UNIX-like system, then you can normally get the
behaviour as you want, by being in normal mode (just press your escape key like
3 times) and then press: `:set clipboard=unnamedplus`.
Neovim will always use the clipboard afterwards until you open up a new neovim
session.

### Persistent

If you want to have that change persistent then you need to create the file
`~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and insert the following:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

### Other resources

For more information read `:h clipboard`.
I assume that you're a newbie to (neo-)vim. I highly recommend to take your time
and go through `:h user-manual` to a better understanding how to work within
vim.

If you want to see all possible options, which you can set in this
`~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file, than I'd recommend to read `:h option-list` to
get a rough overview of the available options/settings.

### Last words

Happy vimming!